# Como salvar imagens no banco de dados usando spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, spring-boot

Estou com dificuldades em salvar no banco imagens de um formulario. Alguem sabe como faz para salvar imagem no banco Mysql usando spring boot? Estou aprendendo agora esta tecnologia, por isso, com esta dificuldade.

Form html:

    
        
            Fornecedores
            Cadastro de fornecedores

```
<section class="forms">
    <form th:object="${usuario}" th:action="@{/fornecedor/save}"
        method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!--Input responsável em guardar o id-->

        <div class="container-fluid">
        <th:block th:include="/mensagemValidacao :: mensagem"></th:block>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"
                    th:value="*{id}">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nome do empreendimento:</label> <input type="text"
                            name="nome" th:field="*{nome}" id="inputNome"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nome fantasia:</label> <input type="text"
                            name="nomeFantasia" th:field="*{nomeFantasia}"
                            class="form-control" id="inputNomeFantasia">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Rua:</label> <input type="text" name="rua"
                            th:field="*{rua}" id="inputRua" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Bairro:</label> <input type="text" name="bairro"
                            th:field="*{bairro}" id="inputBairro" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Complemento:</label> <input type="text" name="complemento"
                            th:field="*{complemento}" id="inputComplemento"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Cidade:</label> <input type="text" name="cidade"
                            th:field="*{cidade}" id="inputCidade" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Estado:</label> <select name="estado" class="form-control"
                            th:field="*{estado}" id="inputEstado">
                            <option th:value="AC">Acre</option>
                            <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
                            <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
                            <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
                            <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
                            <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
                            <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
                            <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
                            <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
                            <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
                            <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
                            <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                            <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
                            <option value="PA">Pará</option>
                            <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
                            <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
                            <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
                            <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
                            <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                            <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                            <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                            <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
                            <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
                            <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
                            <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                            <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
                            <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>CPF/CNPJ:</label> <input type="text" placeholder=""
                            th:field="*{cnpjCpf}" id="inputcnpjCpf" name="cnpjCpf"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Telefone:</label> <input type="text" placeholder=""
                            th:field="*{telefone}" id="inputTelefone" name="telefone"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Categoria:</label> <select name="categoria"
                            class="form-control" th:field="*{categoria}" id="inputCategoria">
                            <option value="Farmarcias">Farmacias</option>
                            <option value="Lanchonetes">Lanchonetes</option>
                            <option value="Material de construçao">Material de
                                Construçao</option>
                            <option value="Restaurantes">Restaurantes</option>
                            <option value="Pizzarias">Pizzarias</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Adicionar foto do perfil:</label> <input type="file"
                            name="" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email:</label> <input type="email" name="email"
                            th:field="*{email}" id="inputEmail" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="exemplo@dominio.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Senha:</label> <input type="password" name="senha"
                            th:field="*{senha}" id="inputSenha" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirmar senha:</label> <input type="password"
                            placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres" name="senha"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"
                        onclick="window.location.href='/funcionarios/listar';">
                        Cancelar</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
    });
</script>
```

Model usuario:

```
package com.bigboss.comprafacil.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.bigboss.comprafacil.enuns.Status;

@Entity
public class Usuario implements UserDetails, Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@NotBlank(message = "Nome é uma informação obrigatória.")
@Size(min = 2, max = 30)
private String nome;
private String nomeFantasia;
@NotBlank(message = "Rua é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String rua;
@NotBlank(message = "Bairro é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String bairro;
private String complemento;
@NotBlank(message = "Estado é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String estado;
@NotBlank(message = "Cidade é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String cidade;
@NotBlank(message = "É uma informação obrigatória.")
private String cnpjCpf;
@NotBlank(message = "Telefone é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String telefone;
public String categoria;
@NotBlank(message = "E-mail é uma informação obrigatória.")
@Email(message = "Não é um e-mail válido")
private String email;
@NotBlank(message = "Senha é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String senha;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable( 
        name = "usuarios_roles", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "usuario_id", referencedColumnName = "email"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "nomeRole")) 
private List<Role> roles;
public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
    return produtos;
}

public void setProdutos(List<Produto> produtos) {
    this.produtos = produtos;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;

public Usuario() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
}

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "usuarios_produtos", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "produto_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Produto> produtos;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getNomeFantasia() {
    return nomeFantasia;
}

public void setNomeFantasia(String nomeFantasia) {
    this.nomeFantasia = nomeFantasia;
}

public String getRua() {
    return rua;
}

public void setRua(String rua) {
    this.rua = rua;
}

public String getBairro() {
    return bairro;
}

public void setBairro(String bairro) {
    this.bairro = bairro;
}

public String getComplemento() {
    return complemento;
}

public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
    this.complemento = complemento;
}

public String getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(String cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

public String getCnpjCpf() {
    return cnpjCpf;
}

public void setCnpjCpf(String cnpjCpf) {
    this.cnpjCpf = cnpjCpf;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>) this.roles;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.senha;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.email;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

}
```

Estou usando o SGBD MySQL

Comment: Qual banco de dados está usando?

Comment: Estou usando o Mysql, vc poderia da um exemplo pratico usando este banco?

Comment: Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-data/springjpa-save-filesimages-mysql-database-lob-annotation). Tem o que você precisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sabendo qual SGBD você esta utilizando, recomendo salvar uma array de bytes (bytearray) como um  BLOB, o [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefblob.html) e [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-binary.html) possuem suporte para esse tipo nativamente. Para salva-lo, basta mapear o campo desta maneira:

`@Column
private byte[] imagem`

Para converter a imagem em bytes, pode-se utilizar a BASE64, um bom exemplo prático dessa conversão é utilizar um servico como o [este.](https://www.base64-image.de/)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Desculpe,estou usando o Mysql. Voce poderia me dar um exemplo pratico para este banco?

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o seu elemento "imagem" já seja um *array of bytes*, caso seja, é só anotar o campo como **@Lob** e é bom garantir que no banco esteja com um tipo que suporta imagens de tamanho adequado para o que deseja fazer. 
Para fins de teste pode utilizar o *LONGTEXT*, acredito que suporta até 4GB.

Na sua entidade ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "imagem")
private byte[] imagem;
```

PS: Não recomendo você salvar as imagens no banco de dados. É melhor utilizar um servidor, como por exemplo S3 da Amazon e salvar no banco apenas a url para obter a imagem.

Comment: e como ficaria o controller para salvar este array de byte? eh preciso converter em base64?

Comment: Não sei como você esta fazendo para conseguir obter o byte[], mas não precisa converter.
É possível por exemplo obter uma imagem de um Path relativo:
byte[] data =  Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path/to/file"));

Para maiores informações: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)